# Creating a React higher order component, to serve as a "loader"(animation) wrapper for child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a lot of components, that require some ajax function being sent, in the componentDidMount method. I would like to create a HOC, whose sole purpose is to "apply" some animation to the component, and stop this animation once a certain promise is resolved.

Of course, i could just copy paste this code for each component, but i would like to create some abstraction that deals with it.

The problem is, that i don't know how to pass the function properly, from the child to the parent. For instance, let's assume the intended child component, has this componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
ajax('/costumers')
  .then(({ data }) => {
    this.setState(() => ({ costumers: data.content }))
  })
}
```

Technically, i need to either pass this function as an argument to the HOC, or perhaps somehow "hijack" the child's componentDidMount(if something like that is possible...). The HOC would then apply an animation once it's loaded, then send the ajax, and only when it's solved, the animation is eliminated, and the child component gets rendered.

How can this be achieved?

Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: this sounds like you need to look into https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux

Comment: I'm fairly familiar with Redux. Can you give me some specific direction? I've never used Redux for such purposes..It was always for fetching some data that will be globally used, for example authentication status

Comment: https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions i think this is what you're after

Comment: I've used Thunk for async Redux actions before, but i don't understand how actions would help me "wrap" my component with functionality. Am i missing here something?

Comment: Separate the ajax call from the child did mount function and put it... anywhere else. At the start of the ajax call, push an action to the state (ajax call started), on an error push the error state, on success push the completed state with data. Have the components react to these states rather than govern them

Comment: I may be missing something about how you want your project to be laid out, but if you're having to pass refs or are thinking of it, you might want to restructure your code. You said earlier that "It was always for fetching some data that will be globally used", doesn't the status of the ajax call fit this criteria?

Comment: "doesn't the status of the ajax call fit this criteria?" - You might be right, i need to think about it. Eventually the goal is to create as friendly code as possible, to just applying this animation functionality to any component that i wish. It seems to me, that even if Redux somehow helps me achieve this, it might be overly complicated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how you can write a HOC for such a case, refer to [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) for more info on the subject.

```
const withLoader = (loader, Component) =>
  class WithLoader extends React.Component {
    state = { ready: false, data: null };

    async componentDidMount() {
      const data = await loader();

      this.setState({ ready: true, data });
    }

    render() {
      if (!this.state.ready) return <div>LOADING</div>; // or <ComponentWithAnimation />

      return <Component data={this.state.data} />;
    }
  };

const Test = props => <div>DATA: {props.data}</div>;

const fakeLoader = () =>
  new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res("My data"), 1000));

const TestWithLoader = withLoader(fakeLoader, Test);
```

Comment: This is so awesome, Thank you! The only caveat here, is that it requires me to provide the HOC an "external" function that returns a promise. I can't just provide it a method from child's class(in your example's case, the function is "fakeloader"). Do you think there is some way, to pass the HOC a function from within the child class?

Comment: Is there perhps a way to "hijack" the componentDidMount method of the child component?

Comment: The whole idea of using a hoc is that it allows you to take out all the logic, then you just have dummy components that are made smart with this hoc. If you can't take out the logic responsible for just loading the data then what you need is not a hoc. Why can't you update the logic?

Comment: Note that if you are making network requests, you should be already using promises, just take that request outside and change it to return the data instead of directly injecting it into its component state.

Comment: `const actualLoader = ajax('/foo').then(({ data }) => data.content);`, but now with the hoc you use `this.props.data` instead of `this.state.customers`. You can also update the hoc to have a dynamic prop name, meaning that it can provide `this.props.customers` if you wanted.